# TeXmaker: Can't change the interface language option

Tags: language-support, latex, texlive

I am trying to switch my Texmaker interface to French.
French support is installed on my laptop and French is set as the main language in my environment.

However, in Texmaker, I only have English as an option: [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxCPD.jpg).

I have tried to force the use of French in command line using
    `language=fr_FR texmaker`
but it didn't work either.

Any ideas?

I am using TeXmaker 4.5 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Here are my locale:
`locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr:oc:en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us what the `locale` command outputs? (Please edit your question and paste the output into it.)

Answer (score 0):

The `locale` output looks good. However, [the files of the texmaker-data package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/texmaker-data/filelist) indicate that the language is enabled via a separate setting in the TeXmaker application, not via the system locale. So I'd advise you to take a closer look at the application settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that! Turned out for some reasons I did not have any of the `texmaker_xx.qm` in the `/usr/share/texmaker/` folder. 
I downloaded `texmaker_fr.qm` as a single file and put it in the folder, now my interface is in French. Brilliant!

Comment: Ok. Then I suppose you didn't install TeXmaker from the Ubuntu archive.

Comment: Surprisingly, I did!

Comment: Weird. The `texmaker` package depends on `texmaker-data` which includes those `texmaker_<lang>.qm` files.